# Sub property in VBA Excel class module

Tags: vba, class, excel

I have a module named cTask with the code below in it:

```
Private pMile As String

Public Property Get Mile() As String
Mile = pMile
End Property

Public Property Let Mile(Value As String)
pMile = Value
End Property
```

So in my sub lets say I initiate

```
dim currtask as cTask
```

I would like to write

```
curtask.Mile=TIM
```

and also

```
curtask.Mile.stat=2
```

just as

```
worksook("qqq").sheets("okko").cells(1,1)...
```

how do I do the nested properties in my class?

EDIT:
so Have in one class named cTask

```
Private pMile As cMile
Public Property Get Mile() As String
Mile = pMile
End Property

Public Property Let Mile(Value As String)
pMile = Value
End Property
```

and in class cMile I have

```
Private pstatus As String

Public Property Get status() As String
status = ppstatus
End Property

Public Property Let status(Value As String)
pstatus = Value
End Property
```

then in my sub all i do is declare

```
dim curtask as cTask
```

Is this correct? It does not work so I must have missed something

Comment: You need to create a `clsMile` class with the appropriate properties, and make your `pMile` of type clsMile instead of String.  Once the `curTask.Mile` property represents an object you will need to use Set when assigning it a value.

Comment: I'm not sure i got all that. I wrote that I did in the edit of my post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example implementation of nested objects

cTask:

```
Private pMile As cMile

Public Property Get Mile() As cMile
    Set Mile = pMile
End Property

Public Property Set Mile(Value As cMile)
    Set pMile = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Me.Mile = New cMile
End Sub
```

---

cMile:

```
Private pStatus As String
Private pNumber As Long

Public Property Get Status() As String
    Status = pStatus
End Property

Public Property Let Status(Value As String)
    pStatus = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Number() As Long
    Number = pNumber
End Property

Public Property Let Number(Value As Long)
    pNumber = Value
End Property
```

---

Regular module:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim Task As New cTask

    Task.Mile.Status = "Done"
    Task.Mile.Number = 11

    Debug.Print Task.Mile.Status, Task.Mile.Number

End Sub
```

---

What's missing from your original question is this:

```
 curtask.Mile=TIM
```

It's not clear what you meant by this: it kind of looks like a "default property" on the cMile class, but that's not really supported in VBA (or at least not easily).

Comment: This worked beautifuly. Sorry about the TIM. TIM ans Status were the same thing I just changed it from the original port to the edit by accident. Just for my understanding what does Private Sub Class_Initialize() do. It empties cMile when the Let or Set of Mile?

Comment: and why sis you use set instead of let for Mile? Thank you so much btw I've been working at this for a while now

Comment: In VBA you use `Set` when assigning the value of an object-type property or variable. `Class_Initialize` runs automatically when an instance of `cTask` is created, and sets the `Mile` property to an instance of `cMile`.

Comment: Actually this let compiled but i et an error when I run the sub:
"runtine error 91: Object vriable or With block variable not set"
I also gwt the same error when I try to assign a value to curtask.Mile

Comment: In your code your properties are declared as String type, so Let will compile no problem, but you'll get run time errors if you treat those properties like objects.

Comment: Can I set different classes cMile for one given ct and then multiple properties status for each?  How do I reinitialise a new cMile class in cTask without and how do I name it in the sub without losing the other cMile?

Comment: If you need your Task object to hold many Mile objects then create a collection within cTask which can hold those Mile instances.  You can then add a "AddMile" method to cTask which creates a new Mile object and adds it to the collection.  Really though, it's difficult to make a good proposal about how you should structure your objects without knowing exactly how you intend to *use* them.