# Sub property in VBA Excel class module using an Interface

Tags: excel, vba, interface

I tried to adapt the solution given in [Sub property in VBA Excel class module](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21767307/5776000) but where `cTask` is based on an Interface. But whatever I do, I get different errors. (I am new to Interfaces, thus maybe I just haven't understand everything so far.)

E.g. when `cMile.cls` stays unchanged, adding `ITask.cls`

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Mile() As cMile
End Property

Public Property Set Mile(Value As cMile)
End Property
```

and changing `cTask.cls` to

```vb
Option Explicit
Implements ITask

Private pMile As cMile

Private Property Get ITask_Mile() As cMile
    Set ITask_Mile = pMile
End Property

Private Property Set ITask_Mile(Value As cMile)
    Set pMile = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set Me.Mile = New cMile
End Sub
```

gives the compiler error "Method or Dataobject not found" (or similar; translated from German). Changing `Set Me.Mile = New cMile` to `Set Me.Mile = New ITask_cMile` neither did work (but I also didn't think it would).

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be like that:
You need to declare the variable `Task` as interface and then `Set` it a new class `cTask`.

#### Module

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()
    Dim Task As ITask
    Set Task = New cTask

    Task.Mile.Status = "Done"
    Task.Mile.Number = 11

    Debug.Print Task.Mile.Status, Task.Mile.Number
End Sub
```

#### cTask.cls

```
Option Explicit
Implements ITask

Private pMile As cMile

Private Property Get ITask_Mile() As cMile
    Set ITask_Mile = pMile
End Property

Private Property Set ITask_Mile(Value As cMile)
    Set pMile = Value
End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pMile = New cMile
    'Set ITask_Mile = New cMile 'works too
End Sub
```

#### ITask

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get Mile() As cMile
End Property

Public Property Set Mile(Value As cMile)
End Property
```

#### cMile

unchanged

Comment: Thank you very much. That works. But why do I have to leave the Properties in `cTask.cls` as `Public` now? All I have read so far states, that with `Implements` they change to `Private`.

Comment: @StefanPinnow If you change them to `Private` then `Set Me.ITask_Mile = New cMile` in `Class_Initialize` doesn't work and you need to change it to `Set pMile = New cMile`. But that will work too.

Comment: Awesome. Hopefully last question: Which of the two possibilities is the preferred one and why?

Comment: @StefanPinnow I would keep them actually private (changed it in my answer). Why? More a feeling than really knowing, but in general it is a good idea to keep everything as private as possible unless you need it to be public. Like you only give a user the permissions he needs and not the keys of the entire house.

Comment: @StefanPinnow just realized that `Set ITask_Mile = New cMile` works too with the properties beeing private. Just without the `Me`. Just in case you want to do something more in `Property Set ITask_Mile` than just `Set pMile = Value` this would be preferred then.